# ¿Como enviar un objeto desde el TabbedPage a los Tab hijos?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Con este método estoy llamando a la pantalla que tiene el `TabbedPage` y le estoy enviando un objeto de tipo `EDeporte`:

```
private void lstDeportes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    EDeporte eDeporte = (EDeporte)e.CurrentSelection.First();

    if (eDeporte != null)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new NuevoRookieDeportesDetalles(eDeporte));
    } else
    {
        DisplayAlert("Atención", SDatosGlobales.MENSAJE_EVENT0_INESPERADO, "Aceptar");
    }
}
```

En la clase donde está el `Tabbedpage` estoy recuperando el objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
public partial class NuevoRookieDeportesDetalles : TabbedPage
{
    EDeporte eDeporte;
    public NuevoRookieDeportesDetalles(EDeporte eDeporte)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.eDeporte = eDeporte;
        validarParametro();
    }

    private void validarParametro()
    {
        try
        {
            if (eDeporte != null)
            {
                ToolbarTitle.Text = eDeporte.Nombre;
            } else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Atención", SDatosGlobales.MENSAJE_PARAMETRO_NO_RECIBIDO, "Aceptar");
                App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Atención", SDatosGlobales.MENSAJE_EVENT0_INESPERADO, "Aceptar");
            App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora lo que necesito es enviar ese objeto a los Tabs hijos ya que necesito su información para hacer consultas a la base de datos, pero no encuentro algún método que me permita sobrescribir la llamada a los Tab hijos y enviar el objeto como parámetro. Esta es la estructura del `TabbedPage`:

```
<TabbedPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CPSiuMovil.Pages.Rookies.Nuevo"
    x:Class="CPSiuMovil.Pages.Rookies.Nuevo.NuevoRookieDeportesDetalles"
    BarBackgroundColor="White"
    UnselectedTabColor="Gray"
    SelectedTabColor="{StaticResource MainColor}">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label x:Name="ToolbarTitle" FontFamily="RookieBold" FontSize="22" Style="{StaticResource LabelDatosPerfil}" TextColor="{StaticResource LabelBarColorRookie}" Text="Natacion" />
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <local:NuevoRookieEscuela/>
    <local:NuevoRookieSeleccion />
    <local:NuevoRookieEspacioDeportivo />
</TabbedPage>
```